# Join query referencing table name causes problems?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a sql query (used with MS Access and C#) that in the where clause references table name with the column, that causes an error. When I remove the table name, it works fine, but it would seem like if you are more specific, it would work better?

Anyone have any ideas why that is?

SQL query in question:

```
SELECT profiles.profile_id, 
       profiles.full_name, 
       shifts.start, 
       shifts.stop, 
       shifts.start_log,
       shifts.stop_log,
       shifts.start_notes, 
       shifts.stop_notes 
FROM shifts,
     profiles 
WHERE profile.full_name=@full_name AND 
      shifts.profile_id=profiles.profile_id;
```

I had to change `"profile.full_name=@full_name"` in the WHERE clause to `"full_name=@full_name"` i.e. remove the table name `"profile"`.

This question came from another SO question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209593/query-is-not-returning-results-in-ms-access-with-c)

Comment: What is the error you are getting? And show the code with which you execute this query.

Comment: Your query pulls information from a table named `profiles`, so `profile.full_name` is not defined because there is no table (or alias) named `profile` in the query. `profiles.full_name` would probably work better.

Comment: @GordThompson Why not put that as an answer?

Comment: @GordThompson I just went back to update my answer on a previous related question after discovering the same. If you put that as the answer, I will mark it as the answer. Thanks! Just wish I saw your comment earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query pulls information from a table named `profiles`, so `profile.full_name` is not defined because there is no table (or alias) named `profile` in the query. `profiles.full_name` would probably work better.